# Mod_Shout Freeswitch on Linux Mint/Debian

Tags: compiler-errors, freeswitch, pbx

I've tried for hours to install mod_shout on my local freeswitch running on a 64 Mint, but I keep getting this error:

```
You must install libmpg123-dev to build mod_shout.
```

I keep getting this error even after I install libmpg123-dev with apt-get.

Does anybody have an answer for that?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but, are you aware that the people developing FreeSWITCH operate and provide a .deb repository? Using this, you don't have to build the modules yourself, but a simple `apt-get install ...` is sufficient. See [this](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie#Debian8Jessie-InstallingfromDebianpackages) for details.

Comment: @gf_ Thanks but i figure it out myself. I download the source package from mpg123 homepage and compile it. After that i recompile freeswitch it works. Seems like the libmpg123 package in the source list is an older version

Comment: What FS version you're trying to install ?